# Selenium Grid Java Client

Tags: java, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I want to create dashboard for QA. It have feature to monitor selenium grid on it. is there any java client or something to get data or control the selenium grid through java code? 
example :

1. to monitor which node is working
2. to modify node (adding capabilites
   and more)
3. etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Selenium Grid Extras is something for you [Selenium Grid Extras github](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras)

> Selenium Grid Extras is a project that helps you set up and manage
>   your local Selenium Grid. Typical instances of the Grid consists of
>   the HUB and Nodes. The HUB is responsible for managing test sessions
>   and assigning new session idle nodes.
>
> Setup of Grid Extras is made to be simple, just run the packaged JAR
>   file and point the node at the HUB location, Grid Extras will take
>   care of the rest for you. Here are the features you get by using
>   Selenium Grid Extras vs Selenium Grid alone:
>
> Ability to control individual grid nodes, following is an incomplete
>   list of OS level tasks: Killing any browser instance by name Stopping
>   any Process by PID Moving mouse to specific location Get Memory usage
>   and disk statistics Automatically upgrade WebDriver binaries Restart
>   node after a set number of test executions Central storage of
>   configurations for all nodes on the HUB server Screenshots at the OS
>   level And much more.

It should simply the managing of grid nodes.